# Google maps api custom symbol

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, symbols

I need a custom symbol on my google maps. I know I can use a marker but then I can't rotate it (I think?) Here is my code:

```
    <script>
    function initialize() {
        var mapProp = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
            zoom: 4,
            minZoom: 2,
            mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),mapProp);
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-51.508742,-0.120850);

        var image = 'http://www2.psd100.com/ppp/2013/11/0601/Aircraft-flag-icon-1106140439.png';
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position:myLatlng,
            icon: {
                icon: image,
                scale: 10,
                rotation: 50
            },

            map: map
        });
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

The marker/symbol does not show when I do this..

Comment: Symbols require a path, not a url of an image

Comment: So how would I do a custom path then?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19675205/create-custom-symbol-on-polyline-using-svg-path/19679919#19679919

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24426400/1238965