# Rotate SVG symbol to match aircraft heading using Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, svg, rotation

I've been trying to rotate the Google Maps API SVG aircraft symbol so it shows the aircraft's correct heading each time the symbol moves. It initially loads showing the correct heading - I just can't seem to work out how to update it to the new heading. I've spent 2 days trying and very much failing. I thought I'd be able to simply change it by adding `rotatation: getTrueHeading` but no such luck.

The only way I can get it to closely do what I want is by adding the planeSymbol instance and the marker instance in to the

```
setInterval(function() {}, 3000);
```

function towards the bottom but this (obviously) duplicates the aircraft icon and seems very inefficient.

I appreciate the code below is not very good so please excuse it's quality - still very much work in progress and I'm also very new to javascript.

If anyone could help I would be most grateful.

```js
function initMap() {
  
 var getLatEl = document.getElementById('latitude');
 getLat = parseFloat(getLatEl.innerHTML);
 
    var getLongEl = document.getElementById('longitude');
 getLong = parseFloat(getLongEl.innerHTML); 
 
    var gettrueHeadingEl = document.getElementById('trueHeading');
 getTrueHeading = parseFloat(gettrueHeadingEl.innerHTML);
   
 if (isNaN(getLat) == true && isNaN(getLong) == true) { 

    // Show default location   
    var usersLocation = {lat: 33.949484, lng: -118.430566};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
   zoom: 3,
   center: usersLocation,
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    });    
    var image = 'assets/images/icons/aircraft_marker_map_none_16x16.png';
   
 }else if (isNaN(getLat) == false && isNaN(getLong) == false) {
 
    // Show flight sim location
    var usersLocation = {lat: getLat, lng: getLong};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
   zoom: 14,
   center: usersLocation,
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    });     
    var image = 'assets/images/icons/aircraft_marker_map_16x16.png';
   
 }
 
   var planeSymbol = {
   path: 'M362.985,430.724l-10.248,51.234l62.332,57.969l-3.293,26.145 l-71.345-23.599l-2.001,13.069l-2.057-13.529l-71.278,22.928l-5.762-23.984l64.097-59.271l-8.913-51.359l0.858-114.43 l-21.945-11.338l-189.358,88.76l-1.18-32.262l213.344-180.08l0.875-107.436l7.973-32.005l7.642-12.054l7.377-3.958l9.238,3.65 l6.367,14.925l7.369,30.363v106.375l211.592,182.082l-1.496,32.247l-188.479-90.61l-21.616,10.087l-0.094,115.684',
   scale: 0.0333, 
   strokeOpacity: 1,
   color: 'black',
   strokeWeight: 1,
   rotation: getTrueHeading
   }; 
   
  
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   id: "player",
   position: usersLocation,
   map: map,
   title: 'Username',
   icon: planeSymbol
 
   });  
   
   //
   
    // Move players aircraft
  setInterval(function() {
   
  var getLatEl = document.getElementById('latitude');
  getLat = parseFloat(getLatEl.innerHTML);
  var getLongEl = document.getElementById('longitude');
  getLong = parseFloat(getLongEl.innerHTML); 
 var gettrueHeadingEl = document.getElementById('trueHeading');
 getTrueHeading = parseFloat(gettrueHeadingEl.innerHTML);
  
   var planeSymbol = {
   path: 'M362.985,430.724l-10.248,51.234l62.332,57.969l-3.293,26.145 l-71.345-23.599l-2.001,13.069l-2.057-13.529l-71.278,22.928l-5.762-23.984l64.097-59.271l-8.913-51.359l0.858-114.43 l-21.945-11.338l-189.358,88.76l-1.18-32.262l213.344-180.08l0.875-107.436l7.973-32.005l7.642-12.054l7.377-3.958l9.238,3.65 l6.367,14.925l7.369,30.363v106.375l211.592,182.082l-1.496,32.247l-188.479-90.61l-21.616,10.087l-0.094,115.684',
   scale: 0.0333, 
   strokeOpacity: 1,
   color: 'black',
   strokeWeight: 1,
   rotation: getTrueHeading
   }; 
   
  
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: usersLocation,
   map: map,
   title: 'Username',
   icon: planeSymbol
 
   });  
  
  marker.setPosition( new google.maps.LatLng( getLat, getLong ) ); 
  map.panTo( new google.maps.LatLng( getLat, getLong ) );

  }, 3000); 
  
   
 }
 
 marker.setMap( map );
    moveAircraft( map, marker ); 

    </script>
    
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEYREMOVED&callback=initMap" async defer>
    </script>
 <!--/Google Map API -->   
    
 <!-- Move Aircraft to Flight Sim Location -->
 <script>
    function moveAircraft( map, marker ) {
        
        var getLatEl = document.getElementById('latitude');
        getLat = parseFloat(getLatEl.innerHTML);
        var getLongEl = document.getElementById('longitude');
        getLong = parseFloat(getLongEl.innerHTML);
        
        marker.setPosition( new google.maps.LatLng( getLat, getLong ) );
        map.panTo( new google.maps.LatLng( getLat, getLong ) );
    
    };
    </script>
```

Comment: possible related question (has an SVG airplane symbol animated along a polyline): [Create custom symbol on polyline using SVG path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19675205/create-custom-symbol-on-polyline-using-svg-path)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the heading from the DOM just like you do the coordinates and use it to set the `rotation` property of the icon.

```
// read the value for the heading from the DOM
var gettrueHeadingEl = document.getElementById('trueHeading');
getTrueHeading = parseFloat(gettrueHeadingEl.innerHTML);

// set the rotation property of the icon
marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(getLat, getLong));
var newIcon = marker.getIcon()
newIcon.rotation = getTrueHeading;
marker.setIcon(newIcon);
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/1gmLj7a2/6/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {

  var getLatEl = document.getElementById('latitude');
  getLat = parseFloat(getLatEl.innerHTML);

  var getLongEl = document.getElementById('longitude');
  getLong = parseFloat(getLongEl.innerHTML);

  var gettrueHeadingEl = document.getElementById('trueHeading');
  getTrueHeading = parseFloat(gettrueHeadingEl.innerHTML);

  if (isNaN(getLat) == true && isNaN(getLong) == true) {

    // Show default location      
    var usersLocation = {
      lat: 33.949484,
      lng: -118.430566
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 3,
      center: usersLocation,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    });
    var image = 'assets/images/icons/aircraft_marker_map_none_16x16.png';

  } else if (isNaN(getLat) == false && isNaN(getLong) == false) {

    // Show flight sim location
    var usersLocation = {
      lat: getLat,
      lng: getLong
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 8,
      center: usersLocation,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    });
    var image = 'assets/images/icons/aircraft_marker_map_16x16.png';

  }

  var planeSymbol = {
    path: 'M362.985,430.724l-10.248,51.234l62.332,57.969l-3.293,26.145 l-71.345-23.599l-2.001,13.069l-2.057-13.529l-71.278,22.928l-5.762-23.984l64.097-59.271l-8.913-51.359l0.858-114.43 l-21.945-11.338l-189.358,88.76l-1.18-32.262l213.344-180.08l0.875-107.436l7.973-32.005l7.642-12.054l7.377-3.958l9.238,3.65 l6.367,14.925l7.369,30.363v106.375l211.592,182.082l-1.496,32.247l-188.479-90.61l-21.616,10.087l-0.094,115.684',
    scale: 0.0333,
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    color: 'black',
    strokeWeight: 1,
    rotation: getTrueHeading,
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(400, 400)
  };


  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    id: "player",
    position: usersLocation,
    map: map,
    title: 'Username',
    icon: planeSymbol

  });

  //
  var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
      map: map,
      path: []
    })
    // Move players aircraft
  setInterval(function() {

    var getLatEl = document.getElementById('latitude');
    getLat = parseFloat(getLatEl.innerHTML);
    var getLongEl = document.getElementById('longitude');
    getLong = parseFloat(getLongEl.innerHTML);
    var gettrueHeadingEl = document.getElementById('trueHeading');
    getTrueHeading = parseFloat(gettrueHeadingEl.innerHTML);

    var planeSymbol = {
      path: 'M362.985,430.724l-10.248,51.234l62.332,57.969l-3.293,26.145 l-71.345-23.599l-2.001,13.069l-2.057-13.529l-71.278,22.928l-5.762-23.984l64.097-59.271l-8.913-51.359l0.858-114.43 l-21.945-11.338l-189.358,88.76l-1.18-32.262l213.344-180.08l0.875-107.436l7.973-32.005l7.642-12.054l7.377-3.958l9.238,3.65 l6.367,14.925l7.369,30.363v106.375l211.592,182.082l-1.496,32.247l-188.479-90.61l-21.616,10.087l-0.094,115.684',
      scale: 0.0333,
      strokeOpacity: 1,
      color: 'black',
      strokeWeight: 1,
      rotation: getTrueHeading,
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(400, 400)

    };

    if (marker && marker.setPosition) {
      marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(getLat, getLong));
      var newIcon = marker.getIcon()
      newIcon.rotation = getTrueHeading;
      marker.setIcon(newIcon);
      polyline.getPath().push(marker.getPosition());
    } else {
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: usersLocation,
        map: map,
        title: 'Username',
        icon: planeSymbol

      });
    }
    map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(getLat, getLong));

  }, 3000);


  marker.setMap(map);
  //  moveAircraft(map, marker);

}
var angle = 0;

function simulateMovement() {
  angle += 1;
  var newPt = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(new google.maps.LatLng(42, -72), 100000, angle);
  document.getElementById('latitude').innerHTML = newPt.lat();
  document.getElementById('longitude').innerHTML = newPt.lng();
  var heading = angle + 90;
  document.getElementById('trueHeading').innerHTML = heading;
}
setInterval(simulateMovement, 1000);
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="latitude">42</div>
<div id="longitude">-72</div>
<div id="trueHeading">90</div>
<div id="map"></div>
```